# When performing a search/query, modify the appearance/reading of a field

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

When executing a search/query, I wanted to be able to edit the reading/visual of a field. The field is data. I'm Brazilian, so the way the date is converted is in the American standard, I wanted to convert it to the Brazilian standard, but not change the format in the bank, but only when showing this value.

Is this possible?

Below is a printout and the very simple code of my query

[image]

```
$data = Schedule::query();
$data = $data->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$data = Order::query()->paginate(10)->transform(function ($item, $key) {
             $item->date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item->date, 'UTC')->setTimezone('America/Sao_Paulo')->format('Y-m-d');
             return $item;
});
```

one of the good approaches is just iterating the values and then try to map them into something else.
you may use `transform`, `map`, or even an `API resource` for doing this.